# How can I save the previous state in a way that allows it to be entered again with GKStateMachine?

Tags: ios, swift, state-machine, gameplay-kit

I am using GKStateMachine to keep track of the state of tiles in my game.

When I place an item, the tiles that are covered by the item are put into a "planned" state. How can I store and then return the tiles to the previous state at a later point?

Here are the parts of the code I figure are relevent to my question. Happy to share more on specific requests.

```
//...
// Have previously entered the tiles stored in the global Game object into a state which is not "planned" state
  class func movePlannedObject(x: Int, y: Int) {

    //DO Some things

    for tile in Game.sharedInstance.plannedBuildingTiles {
      tile.stateMachine.enterState(tile.previousState!)
    }

    // Set new position and change state of tiles to planned

  }

//...
```

And the state machine:

```
class TileState : GKState{

  var tile : Tile?

  init( tile: Tile ) {
    super.init()
    self.tile = tile
  }
}


class TileTileState: TileState {
}

class TileGrassState: TileState {
}

class TilePathState: TileState {
}

class TilePlanState: TileState {

  override func didEnterWithPreviousState(previousState: GKState?) {
    super.didEnterWithPreviousState(previousState)

    tile?.previousState = // What?
    print(tile?.previousState)

    Game.sharedInstance.plannedBuildingTiles.append(tile!)
  }

}
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Relequestual/dac6d51c923e5ce4224e

If I set previousState to previousState, I cannot then enter the state using that vairable...

```
// In the tile class
var previousState: GKState?

// In states function didEnterWithPreviousState
tile?.previousState = previousState

// Elsewhere
tile.stateMachine.enterState(tile.previousState!)
```

Compile time error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'GKState' to expected argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')
```

Comment: Some kind folk on #swift-lang helped me solve this one. I'll be posting the solution hopefully next week.

Comment: how did you end up solving this?

Comment: @mfessenden Sorry I was "that person" who didn't post their solution. Here is the abbirdged version: https://gist.github.com/Relequestual/548c0f858f04e2d2a07550a1e6125afe - Turns out I didn't actually want to do this, but I dug out the code from my git history for you =] Let me know if I can help any further.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Why did you decide you didn't want to use this method? I was trying to shift the game easily out of any state as well into Pause, but now I'm questioning the usefulness of that approach myself.

Comment: I initially needed to do this because I was setting the state of a tile, from whatever type of tile it was (grass or tile), to a build state (show different colour), and then return to the type of tile it was before. I thought about it, and concluded that it wasn't a good way to do it. Based on your requirements, I'm not sure what would be best, but it sounds like a global boolean which tracks paused state would be better than leaving the previous game state.

Comment: That's kind of how I'm leaning as well...thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Will be exciting to get back into this project. I have quite a bit of work to do!!

Answer (score 1):

In case this question is not answered yet, this could be one solution : swift :

Declare a var in your main game class:

```
var previousState: AnyClass?
```

GKState class has a willExit function, in this function you can define this var, because this same class is going to be the previous state :

```
override func willExit(to nextState: GKState) {

    self....?.previousState = ThisClassState.self
}
```

Then in your main game class, you can call this var :

```
self.myGameStateMachine?.enter(self.previousState)
```

I hope this is enough clear to make you go on.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't considered that when willExit is called, the current state will be self, because it hasn't yet changed. I'm not sure I actually need to do this anymore, so haven't checked the code myself. Looks good though.

Comment: I did actually solve this another way. I should post my solution. It's in the comments for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create property in your scene or StateClass

```
var previousState: GKState?
```

Update property in your GKStates didEnter method

```
override func didEnter(from previousState: GKState?) {
    super.didEnter(from: previousState)
    self.previousState = previousState
}
```

And to use it call

```
if let previousState = previousState {
    stateMachine.enter(type(of: previousState))
}
```